# Anylogic: How to move transporter using Trip (travel) time?

Tags: time, move, anylogic

I would like to use transporters in my model. The paths in the model are not to scale. How can I move the transporter between the nodes based on travel time?

For example, the same transporter has to be moved between nodes A and B and should do the movement in x mins but if it has to move from node C to node D, it should take y mins. This calls for dynamically updating the speed of the transporter (In the Move By Transporter" block). I am trying to duplicate the "Movement is Defined by: Trip time" functionality found in the "MoveTo" block to the "MoveByTransporter" block. [Image: "MoveTo" block functionality that I am trying to add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyhLQ.jpg). How do I achieve this?

The reason I need to do this is because exact locations to scale are not known at the moment however, I know how much time it should take for every movement.

I was trying to use length of paths connecting the nodes to define the distance between the nodes. Then dividing this by the time I want it to take to traverse this distance to arrive at a speed and then feeding this speed to the transporter. However, since this distance will change, this approach is not viable.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your approach is exactly right Just make it dynamic.

Use the `distance` function belonging to the [RoutData API](https://file:///C:/Program%20Files/AnyLogic%208.8%20Professional/plugins/com.anylogic.ui_8.8.1.202210270952/resources/help/en/library-reference-guides/material-handling-library/routedata-api.html#routedata-api)
and measure the distance of the path that the transporter will take using the `findShortestPath` function of the [TransporterFleet](https://file:///C:/Program%20Files/AnyLogic%208.8%20Professional/plugins/com.anylogic.ui_8.8.1.202210270952/resources/help/en/library-reference-guides/material-handling-library/transporterfleet.html#transporterfleet) object.

Good luck!

Comment: Yossi, thanks for responding. I tried putting in a RouteData API for the transporter but could not find it in the library. Is there a sample implementation model you could share please?